# How to round up digit?

Tags: objective-c

I'm making calculation for my account that only take precise value like 1.256 > 1.26.
I want to round up digit, i search many things like `roundf,floorf...` but that works like :

```
 IF float myFloat = 1.56 THEN myFloat = 2.0.
```

But i want my calculation like :

```
float myFloat = 1.235 then myFloat = 1.240.
```

That it's not effecting my main digit.It effect only on second place after dot.
so it not effecting digit before dot(.).

How do i achieve  this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to multiple and divide by 100:

```
float myFloat = 1.235;
float roundedFloat = roundf(myFloat * 100.0) / 100.0;
```

`roundedFloat` will be equal to `1.24`.

Comment: for 76859.8828 it take 76859.89 why ? Isn't it like if it is above 0.15 than it increase otherwise same as it.

Comment: Try using `double` instead of `float` and change `roundf` to `round`.